# Why can't I restart cron daemon in 12.04 LTS?

Tags: cron, upstart

I just changed the timezone on my server and therefore need to restart crond so that it will pickup the change, but when I try, this is what happens:

```
root@s2:/# service cron restart
stop: Unknown job: cron
start: Unknown job: cron
```

or

```
root@s2:/# /etc/init.d/cron restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service cron restart
initctl: Unknown job: cron

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop cron ; start cron. The restart(8) utility is also available.
```

The process list says:

```
root@s2:/# ps aux | grep cron
root     10051  0.0  0.1  21992   732 ?        Ss   11:09   0:00 cron
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Try running "service cron restart" as root, or "sudo" it. I'd love to answer this, but apparently, I can't.  106 !>10 apparently.

Answer (score 5):

> What am I doing wrong please?

You should run `service` with root permissions:

```
:~$ sudo service cron restart
cron stop/waiting
cron start/running, process 6325
```

Answer (score 2):

> initctl: Unknown job: cron
>
> stop: Unknown job: cron
> start: Unknown job: cron

These are indications that something very wicked is going on with cron. You may need to reinstall cron to get everything working again:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall cron
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong, it's just making a suggestion.  Instead of doing that whole deal with .../init.d/...., you can just type:

```
service cron restart
```

That's ALL it's trying to tell you.